# disable row of radio buttons in a table

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a table of radio buttons as shown in the below picture. I need to disable the entire row of the checked radio button **except** the checked radio button of the same row. In the **sub-table** of the radio buttons, **i** indicates rows, and **j** indicates columns and an **array(checkedRadioBtn)** is used to track the checked radio buttons. In checkedRadioBtn = [3,2] where **indexes are columns** and **values are rows** and rows are fixed to 4 but columns are dynamic. I actually came up with the 2 solutions which are working partially.

- `<input type="radio" [disabled]="checkedRadioBtn[i] == i && checkedRadioBtn[j] !== i">`
  this becomes invalid on chekedRadioBtn[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaCNW.png) where are less columns
- `<input type="radio" [disabled]="checkedRadioBtn[i % columns.length] == i && checkedRadioBtn[j] !== i">`

what I need is just the logic that goes inside `[disabled]` or any other way to achieve the above-mentioned problem and follow [this link](https://www.assessmentday.co.uk/situational-judgement-test/index.php) and take that test(check answering feature) and it has the exact answering feature that I am trying to implement. any help is very much appreciated. thank you.
[stackblitz sample demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-oevaw4?file=src/app/app.component.ts)
[image]

Comment: Please, add a minimal representation of your work at StackBlitz.

Comment: ok I will add but you can check the link. it has same answering functionality@ZunayedShahriar

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m4zyyg?file=src/app/app.component.html) which is my answer to a similar question.

**Result:**

[image]

So, you can see after selecting one radio button from a row immediately disables the row.

**Edit:**

As per requirement, check the demo at [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ahkelv?file=src/app/app.component.html).

**New result:**

[image]

Comment: thanks but this not what I really looking for. you can go through that test link provided. so you can understand the problem better.

Comment: Do you need that type of conditional feature with uncheck?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a mandatory field. The radio button helps in ensuring only one option is selected. However, it doesn't allow users to deselect the option. If you want to implement it with Radio buttons then you can add another radio button that has a value of None this may also resolve your issue.

Comment: the radio buttons of the columns have the same so they can select only one radio button for each column

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="radio" [disabled]="checkedRadioBtn.indexOf(i) > -1 && checkedRadioBtn.indexOf(i) != j">`
this logic worked for me